# Specifying multiple MergeSection values when using LINK task on MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, parameters, linker, merge

Is there anyway to specify more than one MergeSection value for the MSBuild LINK task? (The MergeSection param is the same as the /merge param for link.exe)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee862471.aspx

When calling link.exe you can specify more than one /merge value, but that doesn't seem possible with the MergeSection parameter.

So far the only way I can see to make this work is by using the AddtionalOptions param, but I'm hoping there's a better way to implement this parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to use AdditionalOptions.

In the Link task the MergeSections property is a string value, not an array, so you can only set one string. Link.exe does not seem to allow you to pass multiple pairs in one command line parameter, you must specify a separate MERGE command line parameter for each pair. The Visual Studio property page only allows a single string for the MergeSections property.